# objc warning: "discard qualifiers from pointer target type"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

When compiling this:

```
char *str = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i days and %i hours", days, hours] UTF8String];
```

I get this warning:

```
initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type
```

How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The qualifier you’re missing is `const`. `-UTF8String` returns a `const char *`, so `str` should also be declared `const char *`.

Comment: +1 And this also works the other way around (I came to this question with a similar but opposed problem).