# Objective-C - Converting NSString to a C string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, cstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [objc warning: “discard qualifiers from pointer target type”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329555/objc-warning-discard-qualifiers-from-pointer-target-type)

I'm having a bit of trouble converting an `NSString` to a C string.

```
const char *input_image = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iphone" ofType:@"png"] UTF8String];
const char *output_image = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iphone_resized" ofType:@"png"] UTF8String];

const char *argv[] = { "convert", input_image, "-resize", "100x100", output_image, NULL };

// ConvertImageCommand(ImageInfo *, int, char **, char **, MagickExceptionInfo *);
// I get a warning: Passing argument 3 'ConvertImageCommand' from incompatible pointer type.
ConvertImageCommand(AcquireImageInfo(), 2, argv, NULL, AcquireExceptionInfo());
```

Also when I debug `argv` it doesn't seem right. I see values like:

```
argv[0] contains 99 'c' // Shouldn't this be "convert"?
argv[1] contains 0 '\100' // and shouldn't this be the "input_image" string?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Richard is correct, here is an example using [`strdup`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html) to suppress the warnings.

```
char *input_image = strdup([@"input" UTF8String]);
char *output_image = strdup([@"output" UTF8String]);

char *argv[] = { "convert", input_image, "-resize", "100x100", output_image, NULL };

ConvertImageCommand(AcquireImageInfo(), 2, argv, NULL, AcquireExceptionInfo());

free(input_image);
free(output_image);
```

Answer (score 2):

The warning is because you are passing a `char const **` (pointer-to-pointer-to-const-char) where the API expects a `char **` (pointer-to-pointer-to-char, in particular a NULL-terminated list of non-const C strings).
My point being the `const` makes the pointer types incompatible.  The safe way to get around that is to *copy* the UTF8 strings into non-const C-string buffers; the unsafe way is to cast.

Comment: I thought as much thanks to @LucasTizma's comments. How would I go about casting the API `char *` to a `const char *`?

Comment: You will need to use something like `strdup` to copy the strings, then you will be responsible for freeing all duplicated strings. As I said in the other comment this is the fault of `ConvertImageCommand`. If this is your code the best way is to change the parameter to be `const char **`.

Comment: don't forget to `free()` the string `strdup` returns.

Answer (score 1):

Use [cStringUsingEncoding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/cStringUsingEncoding%3a) or [getCString:maxLength:encoding:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/getCString%3amaxLength%3aencoding%3a)

Comment: UTF8String also returns a C string.

Comment: @LucasTizma: See my updated code. I'm still receiving the warning.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329555/objc-warning-discard-qualifiers-from-pointer-target-type

Comment: @LucasTizma: If I'm not mistaken, I believe I am doing the exact same thing as that answer already?

Comment: But you're declaring a C array of `char *`s, not `const char *`s, right?

Comment: I see, I see. I'm declaring the C array of `char *` because `ConvertImageCommand()` takes an array that is `char **`. So if I declare my array as `const char *` I get a warning: `passing argument 3 of 'ConvertImageCommand' from incompatible pointer type`

Comment: That is the fault of `ConvertImageCommand()`, if `ConvertImageCommand()` does not modify the strings in the array in any way it should have declared it as a `const`