# Convert NSString to char str[]

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I am trying to convert NSString to char str[]

i have tried this

```
NSString *data = @"08052678744default0000000";
char mac [[data length]];
strncpy(mac ,[data UTF8String], [data length]);
```

But got the wrong result.

Your help is urgently needed in resolving this. Thanks

Comment: What language is this? ObjC?

Comment: maybe you are logging it with %@ when you should with %s

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo, it is half `ANSI-C`.

Comment: yup..Objective C.. but I want to get the same effect as char str[] = "mystring"; but with NSString

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example:

```
NSString *data = @"08052678744default0000000";
const char* utf8String = [data UTF8String];
size_t len = strlen(utf8String) + 1;

char mac [len];
memcpy(mac, utf8String, len);
```

Note the difference between string length and byte length!

Comment: yup..Objective C.. but I want to get the same effect as char str[] = "mystring"; but with  NSString.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7500472/865175) helped me instead of this answer.