# how to convert const char * argv[] in NSArray in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I just want to convert the const char * argv[] in main method to NSArray or NSMutableArray. But I am really stuck and couldn't find any solution.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: No need to down vote the question if you don't have answer.

Comment: @Downvoter Please explain

Comment: Please consider adding some actual code you wrote in your attempts to solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You have a C-array of `char *` (C strings). You need to convert each C string into an `NSString`. Then you can add each `NSString` to your `NSMutableArray`.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:argv[i] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [results addObject:str];
    }
}
```

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++). I didn't understand why( i < argc)

Comment: I am getting error for  for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)  line saying that comparision between pointer and interger("int" and "Char **") how to fix this?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7500472/865175) helped me instead of this answer.

Comment: @PaulSubhajit Because argc is the number of arguments, not the index of the last argument